# MediaRecorder cuts off end of file

Tags: java, android, audio, mediarecorder

In my application, I am recording audio in m4a (AAC encoded) using MediaRecorder.  All my recordings are cut short (by about half a second).  For the purposes of my application, it is important that I have the entire file.  Is this a bug or is there something I am missing?

Record Code:

```
       //set up recorder
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setAudioChannels(1);
        recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);
        recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

        //begin recording
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
```

Stop Record Code:

```
        //stop recording
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
```

Comment: Is it possible to just record an extra half second, to fix this case?

Comment: That's currently the workaround I'm using and I'm not happy with it because it slows down the flow of my application.  It needs to work quickly and it needs to make another recording as soon as the first one finishes, so that half second delay introduces a half second application delay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Android's AAC based audio encoders. The only solution I have found that works is to use an AMR based audio encoder. Unfortunately, AMR_WB doesn't sound all that great for anything other than human voice.

```
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
```

The only other option, as near as I can tell, is to use and AudioRecord, which is much more difficult.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked on this, but I ended up using AudioRecord anyway.